# How to get the + - / * from char

Tags: c#, visual-studio, char, symbols

I know how to work this syntax in C#               `int g += 5;`
How I can do the same if I have char `h = '+';`   kind of `g h= 5;`
or `var j = Convert.ToSymbol(h)`  and after               `g j= 5;`

If won't use switch case

Comment: You can't insert a `char` in an expression since you do not build expressions as strings. Instead, what you can try to do, is make a function that based on the parameter `h` returns different results i.e. `if (h == '+') { return g + 5; } else if (h == '-') { return g - 5; } //etc`

Comment: You need to improve your question a bit. What's wrong with `switch`? Try to add reasons for your constraints.

Comment: just to be able to write code shorter, I didn't insert all of my code to easily understand what I want

Comment: So your goal is to write unreadable code?

Answer (score 2):

C# doesn't have a built-in way of handling symbols at run-time. Not every language out there is LISP :)

In the general case, you're talking about a compiler - something that takes code as input, and produces executable. There's many ways to invoke the C# compiler in C#, and they're very easy  to find, so I'm not going to go deeper into this - it's likely a huge overkill, and presents many troubles with security etc. If you go with run-time code generation at all, `Expression`s might be a decent compromise between security and flexibility.

In a more specific case, you really want to define your operations the way you want them, which gives you full control over the operations you allow the user (be it a live user or some script, no difference).

Indeed, a simple `switch` is the clearest solution for something as simple as this. It doesn't scale well if you want to expand to a full-blown domain-specific language, but it doesn't need any special knowledge (e.g. compiler theory) - just do the simplest thing that works.

```
switch (operator)
{
  case '+': return op1 + op2;
  case '-': return op1 - op2;
  ...
}
```

Don't make things more complicated than they need to be. Especially when it comes to things like run-time code generation or evaluation :)